# Structuring content in Expression Engine

Tags: php, content-management-system, expressionengine

I need some help figuring out the best way to sctructure content using Expression Engine. I've red the documentation, looked at all information I could find but I haven't found the answer. I hope someone here could help.

What I want to create is a product catalogue that would look like this:

`/bikes` (product category, displays the product families, two-wheelers, three wheelers etc.)

`/bikes/two-wheelers` (product family, displays the products in the family)

`/bikes/two-wheelers/red-bike` (product)

`/bikes/two-wheelers/red-bike/wheels` (optional product details page)

I understand that EE URI's are template-group/template based and that the content is in channels. I'm not yet sure how categories can be used in this.
Essentially I would like to create "simple" parent-child relationschips between the entries and I found a plug-in called Structure that does something like that. Unfortunately, this project needs to be done without additional (payed) plug-ins.

Is it possible for the `product` to be the channel, and `product-family` and `product-category` to be attributes of the `product` in EE? Would that work? Is there a better way to structure that?

I realise that this isn't a straight-forward question, but I'm still hoping to be pointed in the right direction. 
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably what you'll want to do is use categories to break your products up into families. You can nest the categories like so:

- Bikes

  - Two Wheelers
  - Three Wheelers
  - Tall

You'd then assign your "Red Bike" channel entry the category of "Bikes" and "Two Wheelers".

For the extra product detail page, you could probably use related entries. Set up a channel called "Wheel Types", then publish entries for all the different kinds of wheels. Then use a relationship field type in your "Products" channel to associate a specific wheel type to your "Red Bike" entry. You can then link to that detail page using a related entries tag in your template.

The Structure module would really help you easily craft the URLs you are looking for, but if you can't use it then the [Freebie extension](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freebie) should help. But of course the time it takes you to figure out how to use Freebie for your needs would probably be worth far more than the cost of a Structure license.